# git: can I choose a non-default ssh client?

Tags: git, ssh, scp

My hosting service comes with a remote login service which includes `git`, but doesn't provide `ssh`, which makes it a bit awkward to work with.  It *does* have `scp`, however.

Is it possible to tell `git` to use a different ssh client than `ssh`, e.g. `scp`?

Answer (score 2):

[`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) is related to SSH, but it isn't an SSH client.

As far as I know there is no way to use Git over `scp`. You might find the [Pro Git section on protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html) helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but the section on protocols is about the git server.

Comment: Protocols generally require two parties. If a protocol isn't supported on the server it won't work on the client without some kind of translation layer. In any case, many servers simply run the same Git software that you may be using locally (the official command-line version), so the protocols apply in both cases.